# Help with my jQuery ajax success function won't fire

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have a JS function that does a ajax GET (datatype: JSON) to a PHP page on the same domain.

I get the JSON response as I can see it via firebug but my success function doesn't seem to execute.

```
function getAppointments(){
var url = "http://site.com/quote/appointments/download/";

    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType:"json",
     url: url,

     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
       alert('success');
       $.each(data,function() 
       {
          var li = $('<li />'); 
          li.val(); //haven't gotten this far yet
          li.text();
          $('#appointment-list').append(li); 
       });
    }

  });
```

}

I get a 200 OK status in firebug and can see the json objects but my alert('success') doesn't fire.

Can anyone see why? I'm sure it's just a little mistake somewhere.

Regards,

Billy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sending the correct headers from PHP? If you are sending JSON you should include:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

To tell whatever opens the script that it is JSON.

Comment: I had set my header but I just noticed I had an extra set of brackets round my echo. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

try using `$.getJSON("http://site.com/quote/appointments/download/", function() {`

Comment: Hi Switz, thanks but same problem again, everything seems fine but no alert

Comment: AFAIK $.getJSON is a convenience function that will eventually call $.ajax in the manner OP has done so.

Comment: It does betamax, but it also has some extra calls in the background suited to JSON that often fix problems people have with normal ajax calls.